# Concatenate year, month, day and time problem in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, dplyr

I have these columns in my dataframe, `df`:

```
year month day hour minute
2013 1     7   21   54
2013 3     20  13   59
2013 1     3   18   40

  .. cols(
  ..   year = col_double(),
  ..   month = col_double(),
  ..   day = col_double(),
  ..   hour = col_double(),
  ..   minute = col_double(),
```

I want to have a new column, `datetime`:

```
datetime
2013/1/7   21:54
2013/3/20  13:59
2013/1/3   18:40
```

I have tried this:

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

df$datetime <- with(df, as.POSIXct(paste(year, month, day, hour, minute), 
                                 format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

and this:

```
df$DT <- as.POSIXct((paste(df$year, df$month, df$day, df$hour, df$minute)), format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

However, it gives me all `NA` values.

- I could merge just the year, month and day with as.Date() though. How can I add times to it?
- Also, how can I sort by datetime later on?

Comment: Also, you should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your original syntax, but make sure you put the right separators between the various components of the date-time:

```r
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~year, ~month, ~day, ~hour, ~minute,
2013, 1,     7,   21,   54,
2013, 3,     20,  13,   59,
2013, 1,     3,   18,   40)


dat$datetime <- with(dat, as.POSIXct(paste0(year, "/", month, "/", day, " ", hour, ":", minute, ":00"), 
                                   format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))

dat
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>    year month   day  hour minute datetime           
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dttm>             
#> 1  2013     1     7    21     54 2013-01-07 21:54:00
#> 2  2013     3    20    13     59 2013-03-20 13:59:00
#> 3  2013     1     3    18     40 2013-01-03 18:40:00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

When you tell `as.POSIXct()` that the format is `"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`, it expects to see a string that looks like that (e.g., `"2013/01/03 13:59:00"`).  Your syntax was pasting them together with just spaces, making something like `"2013 01 03 13 59"` so when `as.POSIXct()` tried to parse the string, it didn't see the expected separators.  You could also have gotten the same result by maintaining your original `paste()` specification and changing the format:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~year, ~month, ~day, ~hour, ~minute,
  2013, 1,     7,   21,   54,
  2013, 3,     20,  13,   59,
  2013, 1,     3,   18,   40)


dat$datetime <- with(dat, as.POSIXct(paste(year,  month,  day, hour, minute), 
                                     format = "%Y %m %d %H %M"))

arrange(dat, desc(datetime))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>    year month   day  hour minute datetime           
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dttm>             
#> 1  2013     3    20    13     59 2013-03-20 13:59:00
#> 2  2013     1     7    21     54 2013-01-07 21:54:00
#> 3  2013     1     3    18     40 2013-01-03 18:40:00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thats odd. arrange() does not work for me t his way. I have 2013-01-07 21:54:00, then 2013-03-20 13:59:00 and then 2013-01-03 18:40:00.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `make_datetime` from `lubridate`. This function accepts the `double` inputs directly so you don't need to concatenate into a string yourself.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |> mutate(datetime = make_datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute))
```

**Output:**

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 6
   year month   day  hour minute datetime           
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dttm>             
1  2013     1     7    21     54 2013-01-07 21:54:00
2  2013     3    20    13     59 2013-03-20 13:59:00
3  2013     1     3    18     40 2013-01-03 18:40:00
```

**Data:**

```r
library(readr)

df <- read_table("year month day hour minute
                 2013 1     7   21   54
                 2013 3     20  13   59
                 2013 1     3   18   40")
```

---

**Update**: This can also be sorted using `arrange`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |> 
  mutate(datetime = make_datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute)) |>
  arrange(datetime)
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 6
   year month   day  hour minute datetime           
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dttm>             
1  2013     1     3    18     40 2013-01-03 18:40:00
2  2013     1     7    21     54 2013-01-07 21:54:00
3  2013     3    20    13     59 2013-03-20 13:59:00
```

Comment: it does not create  this column.. I have checked sessionInfo() and I have R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt). so not sure why '|>' does not work for me.

Comment: Based on your problems with `arrange` (other comments), I'll recommend a full restart of `R`. Alternatively use the `%>%` pipe (loaded with `dplyr`) or avoid the pipe altogether : `mutate(df, datetime = make_datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute))`. The solution is fully working here.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @DaveArmstrong's answer, using `tidyverse`:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyr)
  library(lubridate)
  library(dplyr)
})
#> Warning: package 'lubridate' was built under R version 4.2.2
#> Warning: package 'timechange' was built under R version 4.2.2

test <- tibble::tribble(
  ~year, ~month, ~day, ~hour, ~minute,
  2013, 1,     7,   21,   54,
  2013, 3,     20,  13,   59,
  2013, 1,     3,   18,   40)

test
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>    year month   day  hour minute
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  2013     1     7    21     54
#> 2  2013     3    20    13     59
#> 3  2013     1     3    18     40

test |> 
  unite(col = datetime, everything(), sep = "-", remove = FALSE) |> 
  mutate(
    datetime = ymd_hm(datetime)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   datetime             year month   day  hour minute
#>   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 2013-01-07 21:54:00  2013     1     7    21     54
#> 2 2013-03-20 13:59:00  2013     3    20    13     59
#> 3 2013-01-03 18:40:00  2013     1     3    18     40
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks. do you know how to sort by the datetime column after this?

Comment: use `dplyr::arrange(datetime)`

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(magrittr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  
  ~year, ~month, ~day, ~hour,  ~minute,
  2013, 1,     7, 21,   54,
  2013, 3,     20,  13,   59,
  2013, 1,     3, 18,   40,
  
)

df %>% 
  # pad date elements with leading zeros so parsing works out
  dplyr::mutate(month = stringr::str_pad(month, width = 2, pad = "0"),
                day = stringr::str_pad(day, width = 2, pad = "0")) %>% 
  # parse as actual datetime
  dplyr::mutate(datetime = lubridate::ymd_hm(paste0(year, month, day, hour, minute)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>    year month day    hour minute datetime           
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dttm>             
#> 1  2013 01    07       21     54 2013-01-07 21:54:00
#> 2  2013 03    20       13     59 2013-03-20 13:59:00
#> 3  2013 01    03       18     40 2013-01-03 18:40:00
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>